# Deriving a generator $G(q,p)$ given certain conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

So let's consider a mechanical system in Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism; it has Lagrangian $L(q,q',t)$ and Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$.

I know that $L$ invariant under infinitesimal changes $q → q + εK(q),$ where $ε$ is an infinitesimal value.

How do I find the generator $G(q, p)$ of the corresponding phase-space map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator is the conserved quantity associated to the symmetry of the Lagrangian through Noether's theorem.

In that case, assume the Lagrangian is invariant under $q\mapsto q + \delta q$. Writing $\delta q = \epsilon K(q)$ as you did, Noether's theorem says that the quantity

$$Q=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}K(q),$$

is conserved. Now $Q$ itself is what generates the symmetry transformation on the Hamiltonian picture.

As an example, conservation of momentum. The transformation is given with $K(q)=1$ constant. Then, $Q = p$ itself by definition of the conjugate momentum.

Now recall that the Poisson bracket is

$$\{f,g\}=\sum \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial q^i},$$

so that $\{,Q\}$ is a vector field on the phase space manifold, since it is a derivation. In the case $Q = p$ we have

$$\{f,p\}= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q} \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial p}-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial q}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q}.$$

In other words, the vector field $X$ which must be $Xf = \{f,p\}$ is

$$X = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial q},$$

whose flow moves points along the coordinate lines of $q$, and hence translates in $q$. In other word, the symmetry "moving along the flow of $X$" is indeed $q\mapsto q + \epsilon$ as we antecipated.

Now for the general setting. We want to show that with $Q$, forming $X = \{\cdot, Q\}$ the motions along $X$ are indeed $q\mapsto q + \delta q$ with $\delta q = \epsilon K(q)$.

So first of all, notice that in phase space $Q = p K(q)$. Thus we evaluate

$$\{f,Q\}= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q}\dfrac{\partial (pK(q))}{\partial p}-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial (pK(q))}{\partial q}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q}K(q)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p} p K'(q).$$

Thus our vector field is

$$X = K(q) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}- p K'(q) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}.$$

This means that an infinitesimal motion of lenght $\epsilon$ along $X$ in phase space shifts $q$ by $K(q)\epsilon$ and shifts $p$ by $-pK'(q) \epsilon$.

Well, the first observation is exactly what we claimed, since this means $q\mapsto q + \epsilon K(q)$, while the second conclusion is how the symmetry transformation affects the momenta.

So to answer your question, the generator is $G(p,q)=p K(q)$.

Comment: What's the difference between G(p,q)=pK(q) and G(p,q)=pK(q)+f(q) (where f(q) is a function of the coordinate only)?  Both would give a mapping q↦q+ϵK(q).